# PostgreSQL compare two float8 column datatype

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table `items`. which looks like this

```
|    date    |  id |   s_px   |   c_px   | fee |
+------------+-----+----------+----------+-----+
| 2015-01-01 | 001 | 5355.00  |  5355.00 |   2 |
| 2015-01-01 | 002 | 13240.00 | 13240.00 |   3 |
| 2015-01-01 | 003 | 5840.00  |  5840.00 |   1 |
| 2015-01-01 | 004 | 20.55    |    20.59 |   5 |
| 2015-01-01 | 005 | 64.42    |    64.42 |   6 |
```

column `s_px` and `c_px` had data type pf float8

when I do the compare `s_px` and `c_px` for unequality

```
select * from items where s_px != c_px
```

This returns almost the same original table. I know direct float compare is not easy.
But is there any thing similar to `numpy.isclose`

Comment: http://floating-point-gui.de/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for the link

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The inequality operator is `<>` (or `!=`), so your query is correct.  However, floating point values are fickle.  I would suggest checking to be sure they are not within some small range of each other:

```
select *
from items
where abs(s_px - c_px) > 0.0001;
```